# Java: Basic Math Error?

Tags: java, date, time

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here.  I've got very simple code:

```
private static final long MILLIS_PER_YEAR = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

//...

public long getAge() {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - this.getBirthdate().getTime();
    System.out.println("Computed age:  " + (millis / MILLIS_PER_YEAR) + ", birthdate=" + this.getBirthdate() + ", birthdateMillis=" 
            + this.getBirthdate().getTime() + ", now=" + new Date() + ", nowMillis=" + System.currentTimeMillis() 
            + ", elapsedMillis=" + millis);
    return millis / MILLIS_PER_YEAR;
}
```

...but it's giving some completely incorrect output:

```
Computed age:  248, birthdate=2001-01-01 10:00:00.0, birthdateMillis=978307200000, now=Fri Aug 10 16:56:48 EST 2012, nowMillis=1344581808173, elapsedMillis=366274608173
Computed age:  184, birthdate=2004-01-01 10:00:00.0, birthdateMillis=1072915200000, now=Fri Aug 10 16:56:48 EST 2012, nowMillis=1344581808173, elapsedMillis=271666608173
```

If I run the same computation manually ([or by using Google](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?rlz=1C1CHFA_enAU488AU489&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHFA_enAU488AU489&sclient=psy-ab&q=366274608173%20/%20%281000%20%2a%2060%20%2a%2060%20%2a%2024%20%2a%20365%29&oq=366274608173%20/%20%281000%20%2a%2060%20%2a%2060%20%2a%2024%20%2a%20365%29&gs_l=hp.3...4176.4176.3.4624.1.1.0.0.0.0.209.209.2-1.1.0...0.0...1c.ULiUUIZGxcQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=48bb6b4f4493f288&biw=1723&bih=1128)), I get the [correct result](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?rlz=1C1CHFA_enAU488AU489&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHFA_enAU488AU489&sclient=psy-ab&q=366274608173%20milliseconds%20in%20years&oq=366274608173%20milliseconds%20in%20years&gs_l=hp.3...48355.52023.6.52144.23.22.0.0.0.0.306.4894.2-20j1.21.0...0.0...1c.VMcxOMVOB5Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=48bb6b4f4493f288&biw=1723&bih=1128) (within a reasonable allowance, due to the fact that there are slightly more than 365 days in a real year).

How is it that the same math is producing such nonsensical output in this code?

Comment: In my IDE `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365` comes with a warning that this causes an overflow. BTW There is 365.2425 days on average in a year.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  I'm in Eclipse (Helios) and it didn't give a warning on that line.  Would have been quite helpful if it had.

Comment: I use IntelliJ CE, it has hundreds of warning in the free version and quick fixes for most of them.  I use the quick fixes even when editing i.e. I write the minimum of code I know the IDE can fix for me. ;)  Intellij Ultimate (not free) has over 700 warning, mostly with fixes. I have a commercial license but use the free version most of the time because I can run it on multiple boxes at once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value of `MILLIS_PER_YEAR` is wrong. It's `1471228928` instead of the desired `31536000000`.

Look at the calculation of the value: all participating values are `int` values (numeric, non-decimal constants are `int`-values by default in Java). This means that the *result* of the calculation will be an `int` value as well. But the *desired* value is bigger than an `int` can hold, so you'll have an overflow.

To ensure that the caluclation is done on `long` values, simply make at least one of the values a long (by appending the `L` suffix):

```
private static final long MILLIS_PER_YEAR = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it.  I knew it had to be something basic.  Been awhile since the last time I ran into a practical example of an integer overflow issue.